# Ansible: variable registered on one server gets forgotten when running on another remote server

Tags: variables, debugging, ansible

My tasks:

```
  - name: Init a new swarm with default parameters
    docker_swarm:
      state: present
      advertise_addr: "{{ manager_ip }}:2377"
    register: rezult
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address == '{{ manager_ip }}'"

  - debug:
      msg: '{{ rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker }}'
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address == '{{ manager_ip }}'"
```

Now this works fine, but if I want to run it on another server (!=) with:

```
  - debug:
      msg: '{{ rezult.swarm_facts.JoinTokens.Worker }}'
    when: "ansible_default_ipv4.address != '{{ manager_ip }}'"
```

I get:

```
FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'swarm_facts'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible/docker-ansible/docker.yml': line 42, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"}
```

I do not get it. It is like ansible forgets the value of registered variable called "rezult" when running on another server even though I registered it and it should have a fixed value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, variables are **always** host specific, including ones declared by `set_fact:`; if you want that variable to appear on all your hosts, you'll have to have a special "propagation" action that reaches "over" to the one host that does have the value, and assign it to all the hosts:

```
- set_fact:
    hello: I am a manager
  when: ansible_default_ipv4.address == '{{ manager_ip }}'
- set_fact:
    hello: '{{ hostvars[manager_host].hello }}'
  when: hello is not defined
  vars:
     # you may have access to some less convoluted logic than this
     # to know which inventory_hostname ran that "set_fact:"
     manager_host: '{{ hostvars | dict2items
        | selectattr("value.ansible_default_ipv4.address", "eq", manager_ip)
        | map(attribute="key") | first }}'
```